# JAVA - store an image blob with a fixed size

Tags: java, image, hibernate, blob

I'm trying to save an entity (hibernate) that contains a Blob field.

this blob may vary in size..

my goal is to persist it with a fixed size (10 KB).

format of my images is JPEG, and I would like to keep its original width \ height rather than reducing them (compress not re-size)

losing the original image quality is not an issue.

(on a side note -  the blob is being created form a byte array, maybe the process of size reduction is supposed to be executed on the byte array instead of the blob? either way will help..)

thanks!

Comment: The process of size reduction depends on the format of image, and on how you want to reduce the weight of the image: by compressing it, or by reducing its size. You can't just take a byte array or a blob and apply a magical size reduction method that would work whatever the byte array represents.

Comment: As @JBNizet already mentioned, this should be part of your applications' logic. Just telling an entity to truncate a byte array to a certain size does not make sense at all (data loss).

Comment: check my edit, is it making more sense now?

Comment: Yes, but you got your answer already. This has nothing to do with hibernate and persistence. The image should be reduced before, in the business logic layer. The resulting byte array should then be stored in the persistent entity. Find an image manipulation library that can compress JPEGs.

Comment: @Urbanleg: you won't just loose image quality, depending on the image format it won't even be possible to read the image at all!

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with hibernate and persistence. The image should be reduced before, in the business logic layer. The resulting byte array should then be stored in the persistent entity. Find an image manipulation library that can compress JPEGs. – JB Nizet